# How to remove duplicate strings with odd index line and next even string in text file and avoid it for evens

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to remove duplicate strings located only on the odd index number lines with next even line inside text document about 30 000 rows, and avoid it for even lines content, even must be removed only if it is next after odd duplicate. For example with index numbers content:

```
0. some text 1
1. some text 2
2. some text 3
3. some text 2
4. some text 5
5. some text 6
6. some text 2
7. some text 7
8. some text 2
9. some text 9
```

and must be processed this way:

```
some text 1
some text 2 // keep unique 
some text 3
some text 2 // remove odd duplicate 
some text 5 // remove even because previous is odd duplicate 
some text 6
some text 2 // keep because this duplicate on even line 
some text 7
some text 2 // keep because this duplicate on even line 
some text 9
```

to get this:

```
some text 1
some text 2
some text 3
some text 6
some text 2
some text 7
some text 2
some text 9
```

But I'm not sure how get this result. So seems like I've to read all lines content, and ask for index:

```
if (index % 2 == 0)  
{

}
```

but can't get, how to compare these lines to go further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samples: [Simple](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U6hET2) | [Extended](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jOwoRU)

Code:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("/path/to/file.txt");
List<string> newLines = new List<string>();
for(int x = 0; x < lines.Length; x++)
{
    if(x % 2 == 1 && newLines.Contains(lines[x])) //is odd and already exists
        x++; \\skip next even line
    else
        newLines.Add(lines[x]);
}
```

Read and Write Line by Line - Code:

```
//Delete file if exists
if(System.IO.File.Exists(@"/path/to/new_file.txt"))
    System.IO.File.Delete(@"/path/to/new_file.txt")

List<string> newLines = new List<string>();
using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"/path/to/file.txt"))
using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"/path/to/new_file.txt", true))
{
    string line = null;
    int x = 0;
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if(x % 2 == 1 && newLines.Contains(line)) //is odd and already exists
            x++; \\skip next even line
        else
        {
            newLines.Add(line);
            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
        x++;
    }
}
```

Results should be:

```
+EVEN: some text 1
+ODD: some text 2
+EVEN: some text 3
-ODD: some text 2
-EVEN: some text 5
+ODD: some text 6
+EVEN: some text 2
+ODD: some text 7
+EVEN: some text 2
+ODD: some text 9
```

Comment: Hello, yes that was a wrong explanation sorry, now edited. So this code works, and it is answer. for small amount of lines for sure. So I'm going to mark it as answer, thanks. But one question about it, is it  effective for 30 000 lines? Tell me if I'm wrong, I'm writing it back into the file from  list this way  `File.WriteAllLines(path, newLines);` right? So now I'm trying to check for file with 30 000 lines, and still can get if it is done proper for all. What you think?

Comment: 30.000 lines its not much lines... will run fast.

Comment: the problem is not the speed with your solution, it works perfectly and follow exactly the logic that I requested, but I got exactly the problem about which I was suspected for and need to find some other way. Cause is the rewriting  `File.WriteAllText("doc.txt", out);` because I have active requesting to this file and this code locates inside the textBox_KeyDown event and must be there, to make this sorting  with any actual change. So with 30 000 rows inside the text document program hangs, seems like it is too much for such rewriting, with small amount it work as I said, great

Comment: something wrong here `while ((lines = File.ReadLine()) != null)` with  `File.ReadLine` it is  `using System.IO;` right? So  I have to use it this way `using (StreamReader lines = new StreamReader("file.txt"))` of I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try again please. I forgot to declare lines string variable.

Comment: @ Igor Quirino same, hangs and seems like the cause  is not in the speed of your code, both works exactly as I want. it is because  I have to write it beck with `File.WriteAllLines("doc.txt", newLines);` with large amount of rows.

Comment: Try again now! ^^

Comment: works as all of codes you post, but this one also hangs, so seems like I have to remove this part form event, which is not desirable, but apparently I must. And I want to mark that the given code as previous works proper as I asked in the logic and fast with large files. it is the answer. The problem in my case it is in the writing of large amount of rows with KeyDown event, so it is a different thing.

Comment: I dont know why are you processing on KeyDown event.. Please open a new question or Share more details

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm reading your requirements incorrectly, the following should work (although I havent tested):

```
string[] original = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("path/to/file");
List<string> working = new List<string>;

int i = 0;
while (i < original.Length)
{
    if (i % 2 != 0)
    {
        // line is odd - check whether this is a duplicate
        int dupeCount = working.Where(a => a == original[i]).ToList().Count;
        if (dupeCount > 0)
        {
            // this is a duplicate - skip this AND the next line
            i += 2;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            // no duplicate found - add to list
            working.Add(original[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // line is even - value always gets added
        working.Add(original[i]);
    }  
    i++;      
}

// List<string> working should now contain the output you want
```

Comment: What about this?
text 9 // remove even because previous is odd duplicate

Comment: I just assumed a typo by OP - as the line:

Comment: some text 9 // remove even because previous is odd duplicate - is actually an odd line

Comment: Yes, but Asnivor are adding always "even"

Comment: Only if the previous odd line wasnt a duplicate.

Comment: Yah! Sorry "i += 2;"

Comment: @Asnivor Hello, so if I got list `List<string> working = new List<string>();` and then I have to check duplicate, something goes wrong here   ` int dupeCount = working.Where(a => a == original[i]).Count;` maybe need some editing here or I'm doing something wrong? says "Cannot convert method group to non-delegate type "int".

Comment: try changing to:  int dupeCount = working.Where(a => a == original[i]).ToList().Count;

Comment: @Asnivor  it gives me this result, it is different, but it can be  useful for different case 
`some text 2
some text 3
some text 2
some text 5
some text 6` anyway thank you for support

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have `List<string> all` you loop them like this

```
var duplicates = new List<int>();
for (int i=0; i < all.Count ; i+=2)
{
    if (all.FindAll(o=>o==all[i]).Count>1)
        duplicates.add(i);
}
```

And then you remove elements marked in duplicate.

Comment: Hello, with this code I got this result: `0. some text 1
1. some text 2
2. some text 3
3. some text 2
4. some text 5
5. some text 6
7. some text 7
9. some text 9` seems like ti works for evens, but I want to say this code is also useful and near to be answer on current question